# C# Console app how to execute command after clicking a button from toast notification?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a toast notification in a console application that does do something when the button is clicked. I am following the guide on [how to send local toast notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=desktop-msix).

Comment: Console app can send toast notification, but I don't think it is possible to show/handle activation event. The tutorial you refer only has desktop application (uses WPF).

Comment: Refer this answer , you need to add an AppID so that you can show the toast message. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957475/c-sharp-console-toast-stops-displaying-notification)

Comment: I have no problem in showing the toast message, I just can't seem to find a way to interact when the button is clicked

Comment: See my earlier comment, it is easy to send, but I  wonder how console app can receive 'events' and show any UI, as there is no window handle(HWND).